# reinterpret_cast an iterator to a pointer

Tags: c++, iterator, reinterpret-cast

I've got an iterator of Things. If I want to convert the current item to a pointer to the item, why does this work:

```
thing_pointer = &(*it);
```

But this not:

```
thing_pointer = reinterpret_cast<Thing*>(it);
```

This is the compiler error I'm trying to comprehend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z(v=vs.90).aspx

Just in case, the type of the iterator is `std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<Thing,std::allocator<Thing> > >`

Comment: Why would `reinterpret_cast` work? You might have a mistaken conception of what `reinterpret_cast` is, or maybe the issue is with operator overloading and `operator*` in the iterator type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In

```
&(*it);
```

the `*` is *overloaded* to do what you logically mean: convert the iterator type to its pointed-to object.  You can then safely take the address of this object.

Whereas in

```
reinterpret_cast<Thing*>(it);
```

you are telling the compiler to literally reinterpret the `it` object as a pointer.  But it might not be a pointer at all -- it might be a 50-byte struct, for all you know!  In that case, the first `sizeof (Thing*)` bytes of it will absolutely not happen to point at anything sensible.

Tip: `reinterpret_cast<>` is nearly always the wrong thing.

Comment: You said this, but I just want to clarify for readers:  `it` is not (necessarily)  a pointer -- it is an object.  An object that just so happens to emulate a pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I had just been playing with reinterpet_cast<> because I'd assumed the iterator was a pointer, which is why I expected it to be an equivalent operation. I'm glad I did otherwise I'd still have that assumption!

Answer (score 4):

Obligitory Standard Quotes, emphasis mine:

### 5.2.19 Reinterpret cast

> 1/ [...]  Conversions that can be performed explicitly using
>   reinterpret_cast are listed below. **No  other conversion can be
>   performed explicitly using reinterpret_cast.**
>
> 4/ A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large
>   enough to hold it. [...]
>
> 5/ A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly
>   converted to a pointer. [...]
>
> 6/ A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function
>   pointer of a different type. [...]
>
> 7/ An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer
>   of a different type. [...]
>
> 8/ Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice
>   versa is conditionally-supported. [...]
>
> 9/ The null pointer value (4.10) is converted to the null pointer
>   value of the destination type. [...]
>
> 10/ [...] “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be explicitly
>   converted to [...] “pointer to member of Y of type T2” [...]
>
> 11/ A [...] T1 can be cast to the type “reference to T2” if an
>   expression of type “pointer to T1” can be explicitly converted to the
>   type “pointer to T2” using a reinterpret_cast. [...]

With the exception of the integral-to-pointer and value-to-reference conversions noted in 4/, 5/ and 11/  the only conversions that can be performed using `reinterpret_cast` are pointer-to-pointer conversions.

However in:

```
thing_pointer = reinterpret_cast<Thing*>(it);
```

`it` is not a *pointer*, but an object.  It just so happens that this object was designed to emulate a pointer in many ways, but it's still not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I'd (naively) assumed reinterpret_cast<> would just cast anything, even if it didn't make sense. Evidently not.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip:  Nope, although it will blindly convert just about any pointer to any other pointer even if it doesn't make any sense.  Note a couple of additional things, here:  First, there is a difference between a *cast* and a *conversion*.  The former tells the compiler to pretend that something is actually something else, while the latter tells the compiler to create a new thing from some other thing.  Second, as mentioned elsewhere, there are very few cases where using `reinterpret_cast` is advisable or correct.  Usually it's the Wrong Thing.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip:  Note also that not only will `reinterpret_cast` not protect you from Undefined Behavior, it can actually create a lot more potential for Undefined Behavior because you're stepping outside of C++'s type safety system and taking matters in to your own hands.

Answer (score 3):

The first gets a reference to the object, then takes the address of it, giving the pointer.

The second tries to cast the iterator to a pointer, which is likely to fail because most types can't be cast to pointers - only other pointers, integers, and class types with a conversion operator.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because `*` operator of iterator is overloaded and it return a
   reference to the object it points on.
2. You can force it by `thing_pointer = *(reinterpret_cast<Thing**>(&it));`. But it's undefined behavior.

Comment: I would have +1ed the version of this answer, where point (2) was missing.  But (2) will only work if the implementation of the C++ Standard Library that you happen to be using *happens* to internally represent iterators in this way, but it quite possibly doesn't, so you absolutely should not depend on this!

Comment: That's why there's "But it's undefined behavior." in the answer. I just showed how it should be written to be compilable.

Comment: OK, but I think that from the way you have written it, it's not obvious enough that this is still definitely the wrong thing to do, even though it enables compilation to succeed.  After all, if the goal was just to get compilation to succeed, without semantics mattering at all, you could equally justifiably replace the whole statement with the empty statement `;` :-P

Answer (score 2):

Because iterator is not a pointer. It is a class of implementation-defined structure, and if you try to reinterpret it to a pointer, the raw data of the iterator class will be taken as a memory pointer, which may, but probably will not point to valid memory